# how to not show a downloaded mp3 file to gallery?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

I could download `mp3` files via `AsyncTask` and it works,but i don't want display files from galley in phone
How we set flags or change format to doing it? what is your solution?

Comment: mp3 files are not going to show in gallery.

Answer (score 1):

The best (and unique as far as I know) to exclude a folder from scanning is to add to said folder a `.nomedia` file. This file will just make the file scanner ignore the content of the folder.

https://lifehacker.com/5793803/disable-media-scanning-in-specific-android-directories-by-creating-a-nomedia-file.

Regards,
Matthieu

Comment: i must change save folder name to .nomedia ? am i true ?

Comment: No, create an empty file named `.nomedia`. This file will make media scanners to avoid that particular folder from scanning medias. In your case the `.mp3` which will be not going to showed up in Google Play Music or any other Music player. Happy Coding !

Answer (score 1):

MediaScanner will typically ignore Directories which either

1. Are named `.nomedia`
2. Contain empty file named `.nomedia`

These "flags" should be exactly what you're looking for.

If you save files in "private" App directory they should also be ignored. You can aquire a path to this directory with `getFilesDir()` method.